# Angular, mostrar una variable que se le inyectan datos en una funcion y manipular estos datos en otra funcion

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, ts

Buenas eh intentado varas formas y maneras de hacer esto que les voy a preguntar como por ejemplo, hacer un return, usando parametros pero no sirve intente poner la funcion dentro de otra funcion pero no era lo que necesitaba.

Les explico necesito que esta variable que se inicializa en una array vacia.

```
    canchas: any[] = [];
```

A la cual le agrego datos de un servicio que son nombre de canchas.

```
      getCanchas(){
        this.canchasService.getCanchas().subscribe((res)=>{
          this.canchasService.cancha = res;
          this.canchas = [];
          for(let a of res) {
            this.canchas.push( a.name );
          }
        })
      }
```

Lo que necesito es que la array canchas pueda mostrar los datos que se cargaron en la funcion getCanchas en otra funcion llamada por ejemplo probando

```
      probando() {
        console.log( 'prbando', this.canchas )
      }
```

El resultado del console.log es una array vacia sin ningun dato, espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te está sucediendo es que estás intentando acceder de forma síncrona a un dato que cambia de forma asíncrona. Te recomiendo familiarizarte con el concepto de [asincronía en Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) para que obtengas las bases y puedas entender mejor como funciona el tema.

Pero en resumen, debes esperar a que la función asíncrona se ejecute antes de proceder a usar cualquier resultado que dependa de esta:

```js
const { timer } = rxjs;

class Service {
  numbers = [];

  // esta función se podría decir que es asíncrona
  // porque modifica una propiedad luego de un tiempo:
  loadNumbers() {
    // esto va a demorarse 1 segundo en ejecutarse:
    timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
      // un segundo despues se asigna este valor:
      this.numbers = [1, 2, 3];
    });
  }
  
  readNumbers() {
    // esta función intenta leer el valor de esa propiedad 
    // inmediatamente después de ser llamada:
    console.log(this.numbers);
  }
}

const service = new Service();
// estas funciones se llaman de manera síncrona:
service.loadNumbers(); // esta se ejecuta pero demora 1 segundo en hacer efecto
service.readNumbers(); // este se ejecuta immediatamente después pero no espera 1 segundo
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Ahora, si tu intención es leer ese valor correctamente después de haber cambiado deberás hacerlo de forma asíncrona:

```js
const { timer } = rxjs;
const { tap } = rxjs.operators;

class Service {
  numbers = [];

  loadNumbers() {
    // se retorna el observable para suscribirse a el desde afuera:
    return timer(1000).pipe(
      // se usa algún operador como "tap" para modificar la variable de la clase.
      // este código no se va a ejecutar hasta que alguien llame el método subscribe
      tap(() => {
        // un segundo despues se asigna este valor:
        this.numbers = [1, 2, 3];
      })
    );
  }
  
  readNumbers() {
    console.log(this.numbers);
  }
}

const service = new Service();
// estas funciones se ejecutan de manera asíncrona:
service.loadNumbers()
  .subscribe(() => {
    // esta se va a ejecutar después de que la anterior haya finalizado
    // es decir, un segundo después:
    service.readNumbers();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```